# How to make default format of inputed value in text input field with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an example as like

[image]

in the above image input field, I just put `1` and by default converted `1:00` when I click outside of input field.

I have found many examples but can't be found exactly like this.

How do I do that?

Really appreciate if solved this.

My HTML is

```
<input class="form-control time-count" type="text" name="hour-times" id="hour_times">
```

The JS, it currently just prevents character & add colon `:` after two digits.

```
var time = document.getElementsByClassName('time-count'); 
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) { 
    time[i].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {; 
        var reg = /[0-9]/;
        if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; 
        if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1);
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your html markup?

Comment: provide you html.

Comment: set up an eventlistener to 'blur', check what value you've got, then change/convert the value to what you want.

Comment: @J.Langer updated the question

Comment: The code you've got looks promising. What is your problem now?

Comment: I want while putting `1` or something it will automatically format into `1:00` @Jeff

Comment: If you want to execute your javascript automatically when press 1, try bind the event "keypress" instead of keyup

Comment: _"while putting 1 or something"_ - right now you check if the value has the `length == 2`, so if you want it to already react when typing only one digit, just change that to 1... - but keep in mind, that somebody might want to type '10:00'; he couldn't do that then.

Comment: `this.value.length >= 1 && this.value.length <=2 &&...` but this has negative consequences, as already mentioned